# Solve linear recursive matrix

Tags: python-2.7, math, linear-algebra

I have the equation:

S= C.(BSQ)+(1-C)I where S,B,Q are square matrices of nXn dim,C is a constant and I is identity matrix.S is initialised to identity matrix
I want to solve the equation to find S.Can I do this without taking any inverse on both sides and then simplifying and so on?(I am working with large datasets taking inverse might be very slow)By just using the above equation I got some results but I am not sure if its correct as you cant do three matrix multiplications simultaneously.What can I do to solve for S?

[the answer I am getting after plugging in all the matrices with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjZg5.png)

Comment: Since you do not tell us what the values of `C`, `B`, and `Q` are, even in your graphic, how could we answer your question? And what do you mean by "you can[']t do three matrix multiplications simultaneously"?  Just multiply the first two then the third. And matrix inversion is at worst O(n**3) with simple algorithms, which is polynomial time, so what is wrong with that? Your specific examples may have features that would speed that up to even less time. Please show us your full example, in text, so we can check correctness of your answer.

Comment: Also, if speed is important, you should probably use a numpy array rather than a basic Python list-of-lists.

Comment: I cant multiply the first two matrix and then the third because the first two are B and S and multiplying them will change the value of S.This will be a problem as S is present on both sides of the equation so the value computed would be wrong.

Comment: I am using a numpy array.Should I post my code too?I just didnt post it because its mainly how the matrices are computed individually using some conditions etc.The main part is to solve the equation by using the values of the matrices.

Comment: Once you have a candidate answer for `S` you can multiply the three matrices to check your answer. Is that not what you meant by "I am not sure if its correct as you cant do three matrix multiplications simultaneously"? You still need to show some example values so we can be sure what you mean. They should be reduced, smaller-size examples, according to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can I matrix multiply all the three matrices?Since in numpy arrays you cant do direct multiplication you have to use np.dot(X,Y) but here I cant first do two matrix multipcation and then the third as my RHS and LHS both have S matrix which creates the problem

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your matrices, you might be able to just iterate that formula and hope that it converges. I.e. start with `S=I`, and re-calculate `S` until it does not change anymore. Of course, this is not guaranteed to converge, but you might want to try.

If you want to solve that directly, you can derive a linear system. Just factor the RHS out (such that you get an expression for every entry in the resulting matrix) and set up equations for every entry. E.g. for the first entry, this would look like this:

```
s11 = 1 - c + c * (q11 * (b11 * s11 + b12 * s21 + b13 * s31 + ...) + 
                   q21 * (b11 * s12 + b12 * s22 + b13 * s32 + ...) + 
                   q31 * (b11 * s13 + b12 * s23 + b13 * s33 + ...) + 
                   ...)
```

Solve for the `s..` and you're done. If the system admits a solution, of course. Otherwise, you might want to solve for a least-squares solution.

Comment: Thanks.Hopefully it is converging in this case but its a good tip when it isnt

Answer (score 0):

```
for t in range(100):

        s=c*(sc.dot(sc.dot(Qin.T,s),Qin))+ (1-c)*I
```

This solves the equation recursively 100 times.You can do a convergence test that is Si-Si-1=some small value to check for convergence too.